# Continuity of the fractional Laplacian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Considering $(-\Delta)^s: H^{2s}(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$, is it possible to show that this operator is closed (continuous)?
For instance, taking a sequence $(u_n) \subset H^{2s}(\Omega)$ with $u_n \to u$ in $H^{2s}(\Omega)$, we need to show that $(-\Delta)^su_n \to (-\Delta)^su$ in $L^2(\Omega)$.

**Attempt:**

Consider
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty}\int_\Omega |(-\Delta^s)u_n(x)|^2 dx = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \int_\Omega \Big(\int_\Omega \frac{u_n(x) - u_n(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}} dy\Big)^2 dx.$$

So my idea would be to use some inequality (perhaps something similar to the Poincaré inequality) to obtain the norm of $u_n$ in $H^{2s}(\Omega)$ on the right side. But, I don't know how to get rid of this one on the right side of the expression above.

Comment: 1) Your operator should probably be $(-\Delta)^s$, not $(-\Delta^s)$. 2) What kind of assumptions do you make on $\Omega$? 3) The Laplacian involves two derivatives, are you really considering it from $H^s$ to $L^2$ and not $H^{2s}$? 4) Are you trying to prove that this operator is bounded from $H^s$ to $L^2$, or that it is "*closed*" as an unbounded operator with domain $H^s$ within $L^2$ as the ambient space?

Comment: Hello, first thank you for the reply.
Essentially I'm looking for a domain $X$ where $D((-\Delta)^s) = X$, with $X \subset L^2(\Omega)$ such that $(-\Delta)^s : X \subset L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ is closed and densely defined. And my hope is that it's $H^{2s}(\Omega)$, for example.

Comment: $X = H^{2s}(\Omega)$ works indeed. What is your definition of $H^{2s}(\Omega)$? Indeed, the property you mention can be chosen as a definition of $H^{2s}(\Omega)$ (in which case, there is nothing to prove).

Comment: The definition I'm using is this one. Are the functions $u \in L^2(\Omega)$ whose integral $\int_{\Omega} \int_{\Omega} \frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^2}{|x-y|^{N+4s}} dxdy$ 
is finite. I still can't see why it's closed.

Comment: There seems to be a confusion in your question between the notion of "continuous" operator and "closed" operator. To prove that an operator $A$ is continuous, you need to prove that $u_n \to u$ (in $D(A)$) implies $A u_n \to A u$ (in the ambient space) . To prove that an operator $A$ is closed you need to prove that if $u_n \to u$ (in the ambient space) and $A u_n \to v$ (in the ambient space), then $u \in D(A)$ and $v = Au$.

Comment: Yes, I made that mess. What I really want is exactly a domain $D$ in which the fractional Laplacian operator is a closed operator. I have tried a lot but without success. 
For example, here's a try: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4671340/prove-that-the-operator-deltas-is-closed